# How to add placeholder to Rails 6 text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot seem to find the answer to this.

My tag looks like this:

```
<%= form.text_field :event_location, :required => true, nil, placeholder: "Location" %>
```

Which isn't working, and is throwing a syntax error. How do I add a placeholder to my text_field form helper tag?

I've also tried these which also do not work:

```
<%= form.text_field :event_location, :required => true, "", placeholder: "Location" %>
<%= form.text_field :event_location, :required => true, :placeholder => "Location" %>
<%= form.text_field :event_location, :required => true, :attr, :placeholder => "Location" %>
<%= form.text_field :event_location, :required => true, :attr, "", placeholder: "Location" %>
```

Comment: From an accessibility standpoint you should not use placeholders as labels. Use actual label elements and CSS if you want to mimic that 2010 design anti-pattern. https://joshuawinn.com/ux-input-placeholders-are-not-labels/

Comment: This wasn't a design related question but appreciate the off topic comment.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was simply:

```
<%= form.text_field :event_location, :required => true, placeholder: "Location" %>
```

Not sure why this was not documented anywhere.

Comment: Isn't this the same as your second example?  Hash rocket syntax shouldn't make a difference.